# Unable to attach child to scene

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to attach a Text object to a scene as given under the heading **Handling player die event** http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-13.html

I have an AnimatedSprite which extends Player class. I have created a Player by,

```
mPlayer = new Player(x, y, resourceManager.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), resourceManager.getCamera(), mPhysicsWorld)
{
    @Override
    public void onDie() {
        if (!gameOverDisplayed)
        {
            displayGameOverText();
        }
    }
};
```

The `displayGameOverText()` method is given as,

```
private void displayGameOverText()
{
    mCamera.setChaseEntity(null);
    gameOverText.setPosition(mCamera.getCenterX(), mCamera.getCenterY());
    attachChild(gameOverText);
    gameOverDisplayed = true;
}
```

I have also initialized gameOverText in `createScene()` method,

```
gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, resourceManager.getFontArial(), "Game Over!", mVBOM);
```

At this stage the code works fine and the Text **Game Over!** is displayed when `onDie()` is called.

But when I redesign the `onDie()` method as given below, the Text **Game Over!** is not displayed when `onDie()` is called.

```
@Override
public void onDie() {
    if (!gameOverDisplayed)
    {
        mCamera.setChaseEntity(null);
        gameOverText.setPosition(mCamera.getCenterX(), mCamera.getCenterY());
        attachChild(gameOverText);
        gameOverDisplayed = true;
    }
}
```

This behavior seems strange to me as the code is the same. The only difference is that I have given the codes inline in the latter `onDie()` method.

Can someone help me understand what is causing this behavior. There are no logs written in the logcat regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version you call the `displayGameOverText()` method from within the `Player` class. But I guess that the method `displayGameOverText()` is somewhere outside the `Player` class. Which is why the second version won't work, because the line `attachChild(gameOverText);`actually attaches the `gameOverText` to the `Player`and not to the `Scene`.

The `Player`seems to extend the `Sprite` class, so you can attach what ever you want to the player. Every `Entity` (Sprite, Text, Rectangle...) can be attached to another `Entity` or a `Scene` (Scene is also an Entity). But it does not always have the same effect (or may not even be visible at all)! So I guess that's what happens in the second version. The text gets attached to the Player, but the player is either not attached to the scene, or the text is out of the screen.

When you attach something to an Entity (like your Text to the Player) then the position of that something is always relative to it's parent entity. So if the `Player`is somewhere at position (100,100) attached to the scene and the text is attached at position (50,50) to the player – the text is actually at the position (150,150) on the scene.

Long story short, the line `attachChild(gameOverText);` needs to be called from within the scene and not from within the player.

hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Text object was getting attached to the Player entity. When I attached the Text object to the scene, it works fine `SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().attachChild(gameOverText);`